# jQuery function to loop through elements and set class names based on order compared to an element with a specific class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Current codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVNpvg

```js
function opcWizardry() {

  var $activeBox = $('.box.active');

  $activeBox.prevAll('.box').addClass('done');
  $activeBox.nextAll('.box').addClass('hidden');
}

opcWizardry();
```

```css
.box {
  border: solid 1px #bbb;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.box.done {
  background: #bbb;
}

.box.active {
  background: green;
}

.box.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">box1</div>
<div class="box">box2</div>
<div class="box active">box3</div>
<div class="box">box4</div>
<div class="box">box5</div>
```

I'm currently working on the best way to do this and would love input.

I'm writing a function that will loop through this set of elements that have a class name of *box*. One of the elements in that list will have a class name of *active*. For all the elements prior to the one with the *active* class, I want to set a class name of *done*. For all of the elements after the one with the *active* class, I want to set a class name of *hidden*.

The way I've done it seems unnecessarily iterative and I'm wondering if someone can provide an elegant method.

Comment: you don't need a loop to do this with jQuery, just review the selctors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $activeBox = $('.box.active');
$activeBox.prevAll('.box').addClass('done');
$activeBox.nextAll('.box').addClass('hidden');
```

Comment: There are probably more efficient ways to do this btw, but unless you have several hundred elements on the page with the `box` class, it shouldn't make much of a difference, and this code is much more readable than the more efficient code I have in mind.

Comment: This is cleaner than mine. I was looping through setting a variable when I got to the active class. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, feel free to pick as the correct answer. :)

Comment: Done. You answered it quicker than I was allowed to choose a response :)